# Laurent expansion of $\csc^2(\frac{\pi}{z})$ about $\frac{1}{3}$ for $|z-\frac{1}{3}| \lt \frac{1}{12}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

The question is: Find the Laurent expansion of $\csc^2(\frac{\pi}{z})$ about $\frac{1}{3}$ for $|z-\frac{1}{3}| \lt \frac{1}{12}$. In particular what is the coefficient of $(z-\frac{1}{3})^{-2}$.

I am thinking on the following lines. Do the Taylor expansion of $\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{z})$, and then do the polynomial division $\frac{1}{\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{z})}$. Is this the right way? Is this the only way?

Comment: In the title, is it $|z-\frac{1}{3}|<\frac{1}{12}$?

Comment: Yeah! Thanks. I have edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/determine-and-classify-all-singular-points/346995#346995). To find the coefficient of $\left(z-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{-2}$, just evaluate the following limit

$$ \lim_{z \to \frac{1}{3}} \frac{\left(z-\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2}}{\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi}{z}\right)}=\frac{1}{81\pi^2} . $$

[L'hopital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) can be used twice to evaluate the above limit.