# Evaluating $\int_{C}\left({{e^{2z}\over z^2(z^2+2z+2)}+\ln(z-6)+{1\over (z-4)^2 }}\right) dz$.

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, residue-calculus

Question : Evaluate

$$\int_{C}\left({{e^{2z}\over z^2(z^2+2z+2)}+\log(z-6)+{1\over (z-4)^2 }}\right) dz$$

where C is the circle $|z|=3$. State the theorems your have used to evaluate the integral

**My Attempt :** Integral of the third term becomes $0$ as 4 lies outside the given circle so is analytic everywhere and so by cauchy's theorem it must be 0

The first integral has pole of order 2 at 0 and another complex pole of order 1 for $z^2+2z+2$ which can be solved using cauchy's formula for residues.

*My problem is with the middle integral $\log(z-6)$  as we know that $\log(z-6)$ will not be analytic in the circle $|z|=3$ as it attains negative values which is not defined. so how to go about this integral.*

Please help

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal Thanks for your kind reply !! I mean the second term of the integral :) .. Can you please elaborate how to ork around the second integral with log ? i have this idea that points inside the circle $|Z|=3$ will yeild negative values for log which are not defined and hence $log(z-6)$ is not analytic in the circle. I know i am missing out on some fundamental concept here. Help is greatly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: I just deleted my hint because you had already got your poles.

Comment: What do you think $\ln(-1)$?

Comment: @AmanMittal: Maybe you could take a different branch of $\log$? What is their definition of $\log$?

Comment: can you please elaborate on integral for log(z-6) to explain how you got 0 ? i am not able to see why log(z-6) will be analytic in the given region. I am probably missing out on some concept or have a wrong one :(

Comment: i think its undefined for the usual branch

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal I understand that log is not defined for negative values. btw, the question has log ( base 10 ) not ln someone i think edited the origional question i posted

Comment: @AmanMittal: You can define the usual $\log$ on the negative $x$ axis. It won't be continuous anymore.

Comment: @wj32 so are you telling that the given logarithmic function is defined for all values inside and on the contour $|z|=3$ ??

Comment: As I said in my comment beneath my deleted answer, the branch point is outside the contour, so $\ln(z-6)$ is analytic inside the contour.

Comment: It's possible for the given log function to be defined for all values inside/on the contour, if you choose a "good" branch. (where the branch cut avoids the circle at all). Otherwise, you will need to use the keyhole contour. Have you seen that before?

Comment: @AmanMittal: I already I gave you the answer in my comments and beneath my deleted hint!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Recall that a function logarithm can be defined on each domain of the complex plane with no loop around zero. For example, the usual (natural) logarithm $\ln$ is often first defined on $\mathbb R_+^*$ and it can be extended to $\mathbb C\setminus \{z\in\mathbb C\mid\Re(z)\leqslant0,\Im(z)=0\}$ in the way you know. But a logarithm function $\mathrm{Log}$ also exists on $\mathbb C\setminus D$ where $D=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid\Re(z)\geqslant0,\Im(z)=0\}$, which may be defined as follows: each $z$ in $\mathbb C\setminus D$ can be written uniquely as $z=r\mathrm e^{\mathrm it}$ with $r$ and $t$ real, $r\gt0$, $t$ in $(0,2\pi)$, then $\mathrm{Log}(z)=\ln(r)+\mathrm it$ (other, more intrinsic, definitions exist but this one will do).

This $\mathrm{Log}$ function (or one of its close analogs) seems to be what is meant in your question. Then $z\mapsto\mathrm{Log}(z-6)$ is holomorphic on $|z|\lt6$ and the circle $C=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid|z|=3\}$ is included in this domain hence
$$
\oint_C\mathrm{Log}(z-6)\mathrm dz=0.
$$

Comment: can i do this  :
\\
Root of $z-6=0$ is 6 so 6 is the branch point of $log(z-6)$ and hence a singularity . Now distance of the point $z=0 \from z=6$ is 6, hence, $log(z-6)$ is analytic in $|Z|<6$ and so analytic in $|z|=3$. And hence the value of integral is 0 as said. 

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** You have three poles within your contour, namely $z=0$ with order $2$, $z=-1-i$, and $z=-1+i$. Now, all you need to do is to find the residues at every pole and add them. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367940/difficulties-performing-laurent-series-expansions-to-determine-residues/367956#367956) for a formula for evaluating residues

Comment: yes, that is true only for the first integral. what about the second integral log(z-6)

Comment: @AmanMittal: You have only one integral!

Comment: @AmanMittal: Note that, $\ln(z-6)$ has a branch point at $z=6$ which is out side the contour. However you can split your integral to three integrals and the last two integrals have value zero, since their integrands are analytic functions for the contour you have been given.