# Complex integral confirmation Q

Tags: complex-analysis

Just to check, would this be right?

$$\int_{|z|=1} \frac {1}{8(z-\frac{1}{2})^3} dz = 2\pi i f''(1/2) = 0$$

Where $f(z) = \frac{1}{8}$ by CIF? In the solutions it states $f(z) =1$; or does that not matter, they're both analytic aren't they? Thanks!

Comment: That integrand is a derivative, so integration about a loop is zero. Note the fact that $\left( (z - 1/2)^{-2}\right)' = -2(z-1/2)^{-3}$.

Comment: Just note that, the integrand has a pole at $z=1/2$ of order $3$. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367940/difficulties-performing-laurent-series-expansions-to-determine-residues/367956#367956) for how to find the residue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $ f(z) = \frac{1}{8}$, then by Cauchy Integral formula
$$f^{(2)}(1/2) = 0 = \frac{2!}{2 \pi i} \oint_{|z| = 1} \frac{1}{8(z-1/2)^3}dz$$

Comment: This is what I thought, thank you.