# Using calculus of residues to evaluate a trig integral

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

This is my partial attempt at the solution. I am unsure how to proceed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** You have a pole at $z=0$ of order $5001$ and you need the [formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/367940/difficulties-performing-laurent-series-expansions-to-determine-residues/367956#367956) to calculate the residue.

**Added:** Another approach for finding the residue is to compute the Laurent series of the integrand. Rearranging the integral as

$$\frac{2\pi}{2^{5000}} \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(1+z^2)^{5000}}{z^{5001}}dz.$$

Then computing the Laurent series using the binomial theorem gives

$$ \frac{(1+z^2)^{5000}}{z^{5001}} = \sum_{m=0}^{5000} {5000 \choose m} z^{2m-5001}.  $$

Now, the residue is the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ which corresponds to $m=2500$ in the above series and equals

$$ r = \frac{2\pi}{2^{5000}}{5000 \choose 2500} . $$

Comment: How would I find the 5000th derivative of $(z^2+1)^{5000}$ in order to apply the formula?

Comment: Thank you. There is no $2z$ in the expression it is $z^{2}$

Comment: @MikeMan: I'll correct this. Still you can the binomial approach.

Comment: You are a life saver

Comment: @MikeMan: No problem. You are welcome. It is a nice problem.

Comment: Mhenni: what is that factor of $1/(2 \pi)$ in your first step?