# How to calculate the integral $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^{2x}\theta d \theta$

Tags: calculus

Not sure how to do this one I know it might have something to do with reduction formula but not sure where to go

Comment: Is $x$ a positive integer?

Comment: Use [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

Comment: @B.Goddard yes x is a positive integer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complex integral help involving $\sin^{2n}(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392083/complex-integral-help-involving-sin2nx)