# Show that $\int_{|z|=1}(z+1/z)^{2m+1}dz = 2\pi i {2m+1 \choose m}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that
$$
\int_{|z|=1}(z+1/z)^{2m+1}dz = 2\pi i {2m+1 \choose m}
$$
, for any nonnegative integer m.

I can't solve this problem..

I tried to find singularities but failed.

$(z+1/z)$ is not familiar to me.

Is there anyone to help?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: $z = 0$ is the only singularity. I suggest applying Cauchy's formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula#Theorem

Comment: Here is the [technique](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/389255/using-calculus-of-residues-to-evaluate-a-trig-integral).

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that there were some typos in my answer. Now they are fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to binomial theorem,  $$(z+\frac{1}{z})^{2m+1}=\frac{(z^2+1)^{2m+1}}{z^{2m+1}}=\frac{\sum_{k=0}^{2m+1}{2m+1 \choose k}z^{2k}}{z^{2m+1}}=\sum_{k=0}^{2m+1}{2m+1 \choose k}z^{2k-2m-1}.\tag{1}$$
By Cauchy's integral formula or direct calculation with $z=e^{it}$ for $|z|=1$,
$$\int_{|z|=1}z^ndz = \left\{\begin{array}{cc} 2\pi i& n={-1}\\0 &n\ne{-1} \end{array}\right..\tag{2}$$
The conclusion follows from $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** for $n\in\mathbb Z$ and a positively oriented contour:
$$
\oint_{|z|=1}z^ndz = 
\begin{cases}
2\pi i & n=-1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Now, what happens when you expand the binomial?