# Essential singularities of $\frac 1{e^z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

How do I show that $\frac 1{e^z-1}$ has essential singularities (instead of say, poles) at $z=2n\pi i(n\in \mathbb Z)$?

I can't figure out how to show that the function does *not* go to infinity near $0$, or that it assumes every possible value near $0$. Exhibiting the laurent series around $0$ isn't general enough to show that essential singularities occur at all the stated points.

Comment: The numerator and the denominator seem to be both entire functions. The function $1$ has no zeros. So I would expect $\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ to have just poles, not essential singularities.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/determine-and-classify-all-singular-points) how you test.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't!

The function in question has simple poles. The easiest way to see this is to note that $\exp(2n\pi i)=1$, so by continuity $e^z-1$ tends to zero as $z \rightarrow 2n\pi i$ and thus the reciprocal tends to infinity.

To show that the poles are simple, note that $e^z-1$ has a zero of degree $1$ at $2n\pi i$ so the reciprocal has a simple pole and so the residue is:

$$\frac{1}{\frac{d}{dz}(e^z-1)}=\frac{1}{e^{2n\pi i}}=1$$

Comment: I did not understand this formula to find the residue in case of simple pole, can you explain?

Answer (score 8):

An idea: using, for example, l'Hospital, you could show that

$$\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\;,\;\;\lim_{z\to 2n\pi i}\frac{z-2n\pi i}{e^z-1}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{z\to 2n\pi i}\frac1{e^z}=1$$

so the singularity $\,z=2n\pi i\;$ **is**,  in fact, a pole: a simple one with residue $\,1\,$

Comment: Hi Don, the original numerator is 1...

Comment: Thanks @Ryan, I know, yet a function $\,f(z)\,$ has a simple pole at $\,z_0\,$ iff $$\lim_{z\to z_0}\,(z-z_0)f(z)$$ exists finitely (and thus this limit is its residue).

Comment: Oh yes, thanks, heh.