# Singularities of $\cot(z) - \frac 1 z$

Tags: complex-analysis

Define $f(z) := \frac{\cos z }{\sin z } -\frac 1z$. This is an exam-question. I have to determine singularities in $\mathbb C \cup \{ \infty \}$ and what sort of singularities they are. I further have to compute the Taylor-series around $z = 0$.

For $\cot(z)$ I see that singularities occur in $z_k = \pi k, k \in \mathbb Z$. $\cos(\pi k) \neq 0$ s.t. the $z_k$ should be poles of order one of $\cot(z)$. How must I take $\frac 1 z$ into account ? And how can I calculate the taylor series ? Is $z = 0$ a removable singularity of $f$ ?

Further question: If $\lim_{z \rightarrow 0} f(z)$ exists, is $z = 0$ then automatically a removable singularity ?

Comment: [Related problems](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/determine-and-classify-all-singular-points/346995#346995).

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a simple pole, then the [residue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_%28complex_analysis%29#Simple_poles) of $\cot(z)$ at $z=0$ can be determined as $$\lim_{z\to 0}z\cot(z).$$ (**Hint**: As $z\to 0,$ $\frac{\sin z}z\to\, ??$)

The value thus determined will be the coefficient of $z^{-1}$ in the Laurent series of $\cot(z)$ in the annulus $0<|z|<\pi$. Can you take it from here?

---

In answer to your other question: yes. If it were a pole, then $|f(z)|\to\infty$ as $z\to 0,$ and if essential, then $\lim_{z\to 0}|f(z)|$ fails to exist in any sense.

Comment: Ok nice. I didn't knew this. So the residue of $\cot(z)$ will be $1$ s.t. $\frac 1 z$ cancel out in $f$. Must I then define $f(0) := \lim_{z \rightarrow 0}f(z) $ and compute the Taylor Series via the $n-$th derivatives ?

Comment: The Taylor series of the "repaired" function will be the Laurent series of $f(z)$--as originally defined--with the singular part removed. This Taylor series will provide the definition--no need to state that $f(0):=\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)$. $n$th derivatives of $\cot(z)$ are probably the way to go, but there may be a more tractable method that isn't occurring to me.