# How to find the radius of convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

The function is $\dfrac {z-z^3}{\sin {\pi z}} $. How to find the radius of convergence in $ z=0 $?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried expanding this into Taylor series.

Comment: Ah, but that is a pretty hopeless task. You need to search for the largest disk where the function is analytic, with removable singularities allowed. This function has three ef them.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Looks like three to me. But let's give the OP a chance to work it out for himself.

Comment: Well, the first singularity is at z=0, but it is removable, since the limit is 0. The singularities at z=+-1 are removable too. So the answer is 2?

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I should be $2$.

Comment: @Elensil: The limit at $z=0$ is $1/\pi$, surely? But yes, since there *is* a limit, the singularity is removable.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal $z=0$, $z=\pm1$. I count three still. What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, you are right. The limit is $\frac {1}{\pi} $ of course. My stupidity

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen: I am talking about the radius of convergence.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Oooooh, I see. Sorry, I misunderstood. Your comment came right after mine, so I thought it was a response to that one.

Comment: @Harald: I expected that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to find which is the larger disk centered at the origin, i.e., $D(0,r)$, with $r$ maximum, in which this function is analytic. And as both numerator and denominator are entire functions, the fraction is analytic in those points where the denominator does not vanish. Unless numerator and denominator vanish simultaneously at some point, and the order of the zero of the denominator does not exceed the one of the numerator.

Answer (score 2):

The radius of convergence is $2$ which is the nearest singularity to $0$. The point $z=2$ is a [pole](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/determine-and-classify-all-singular-points/346995#346995) of order $1$.