# Laurent series for $\frac{1}{z^2\sinh(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Calculate the 3 first terms of the Laurent series for $f(z)=\displaystyle\frac{1}{z^2\sinh(z)}$ where $0<|z|<R$ and calculate the highest possible value for $R$.

I've figured out I can do the series expansion of the following using the Cauchy product: $z^2\sinh(z)f(z)=1$, and find out the terms $a_1,a_2,a_3...$ But I think it's too difficult.

Comment: Did you try it? It is not at all difficult, especially as the first two terms vanish. Unless the question is about the first three nonzero terms, in which case the calculation is a little bit involved – but still not very hard.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617221/how-to-find-the-radius-of-convergence/617244#617244).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The zeros of $sinh (z) $ are $\{k\pi i\}_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}$ so the highest possible value for $R$ is $\pi$.

To find the Laurent series note that $z = 0$ is a pole of the first order for $ g(z) = \frac{1}{sinhz} = \sum_{n =- 1}^{n =+ \infty} a_{n}z^{n}$. Then we have $$\sum_{n =- 1}^{n =+ \infty} a_{n}z^{n} \cdot sinh(z) = 1$$
and so after recalling the Taylor series for $sinh(z)$ we can calculate the $a_{n}$ term by term equating the coefficients. Now it's sufficient to multiply by $\frac{1}{z^{2}}$ to obtain the Laurent series of $f(z)$.

Comment: The highest value for $R$ results from the poles for $k=\pm 1$.