# Finding radius of convergence for taylor series of $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion

Im trying to find the radius of convergence for the taylor sum of the function $\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ around z=0.

So far I've found the coffiecients $a_0=1$, $a_1=-\frac{1}{2}$, $a_2=\frac{1}{12}$ and that $a_{2k+1}=0$ for $k\geq 1$. It's pretty ugly to look for the rest of the terms in the series.

Is there a neat way to find that?

Comment: Of course that $z=0$ otherwise how would it be intresting?

Comment: No, I guess what i mean is that we expand this function around 0, when $f(0)=\lim_{z\rightarrow 0}f(z)$

Comment: $0$ is clearly a false singularity of this meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$. It can obviously be extended as an holomorphic function on a neighborhood of $0$ by setting $f(0)=1$.

Comment: since $e^{2i\pi} = 1,$ would not the radius of convergence $< 2 \pi?$

Comment: See [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/617221/how-to-find-the-radius-of-convergence).

Answer (score 1):

Hint: The radius of convergence of a series at $z_0$ is the distance from $z_0$ to (one of) its closest non-removable singularity.

Comment: Can you solve the equation $e^z-1=0$?

Comment: ... closest non-removable singularity.  In general they need not be poles.

Comment: Good remark! I'll modify my answer.