# Asymptotic Expansion in zero of $\frac{1}{\ln(1+x)}$

Tags: asymptotics, taylor-expansion

On [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B%201/Log%5B%281%2bx%29%5D%20,%20%7Bx,0,3%7D%5D) the expansion is:

> $$\frac {1}{x} + \dfrac{1}{2} ...\,.$$

But I don't understand from where it outside comes the $\frac{1}{2}$

thanks

Comment: Are you sure that this expansion is for that function?

Comment: Check what you typed on Worlfram:
$$ \ln\frac{1-x}{1+x} = \ln\left((1-x)(1-x+o(x))\right)=\ln(1-2x+o(x))\sim -2x$$

Comment: Yes this is the expansion, I've calculated with Mathematica.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B+Log%5B%281-x%29%2F%281%2Bx%29%5D+%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2C3%7D%5D

Comment: I believe I saw the function $\frac{1}{\ln(1+x)}$ first when you posted the question.

Comment: I'm sorry guys,I've typed the wrong function. I'm editing.

Comment: So do I!  @MhenniBenghorbal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that, the function has a pole of [order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/determine-and-classify-all-singular-points/346995#346995) $1$ with residue equals $1$. Now, just write the function as

$$ \frac{1}{\ln(1+x)}=\frac{1}{x}+a_1+a_2 x+\dots \implies a_1= \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{\ln(1+x)}-\frac{1}{x} \right).  $$