# Using residue to find a complex integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Given the following:
$$\int_{\varGamma_R} {z\,dz\over e^{2\pi iz^2}-1}, \ \  \ \varGamma_R=\{z\in \Bbb C:|z|=R\},\quad n<R^2<n+1,\,n\in\Bbb N.$$

I want to use the residue for this, but I can't seem to find the poles for the functions

Comment: Did you consider a change of variable which makes the integral very simple ?

Comment: well, no. i'm trying to understand where the poles are

Comment: Because has no poles? $\forall z\in{\Bbb C}\ e^z\ne 0$. And your $\Gamma_R$ isn't a curve!

Comment: $\Gamma R$ is a curve. and I do have poles.with order of 4n+1. I just don't know why.

Comment: How did you know the order of the poles or it is given a solution.

Comment: Is a curve **when** $\Gamma_R=\{z\in{\Bbb C}:|z|=R\}$. And ${z\over e^{2\pi iz^2}}$ has **zero** poles in ${\Bbb C}$. Check again your formulas.

Comment: yep, I was wrong. edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the poles occur whenever $z^2=k$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ such that $k \le n^2$.  Thus, the poles are at $z_k = \sqrt{k}$, $k \in \{0,1,2,\ldots,n^2\}$.  A typical residue is

$$\operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_k} \frac{z}{e^{i 2 \pi z^2}-1} = \frac{z_k}{i 4 \pi z_k e^{i 2 \pi z_k^2}} = \frac1{i 4 \pi}$$

as $z_k^2$ is an integer. Note that the poles are all simple; the factor of $z$ in the numerator ensures that even the pole at $z=0$ is simple.  Thus the integral is, by the residue theorem,

$$i 2 \pi \sum_{k=0}^{n^2} \operatorname*{Res}_{z=z_k} \frac{z}{e^{i 2 \pi z^2}-1} = \frac12 \left ( n^2+1\right )$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** First, find the poles as

> $$e^{2\pi iz^2} -1=0 \implies 2\pi\,iz^2 = 2k\pi i, \quad k \in \mathbb{Z}.   $$

To determine the order, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/determine-and-classify-all-singular-points).