# Laurent Series / Residue Theorem

Tags: complex-numbers, laurent-series

I'm having trouble on computing $\int_\gamma \frac{dz}{(z^2-4)(z-2)}$, where $\gamma$ is the positively oriented circle centered at 2 of radius 1.

Any help on this will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $z=2$ is a pole of [order](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/determine-and-classify-all-singular-points) $2$.

Comment: Your denominator is actually $(z+2)(z-2)^2$.