# Poles (and order of) of $(\cosh(1/(z-\pi)))^2$ and Residue at $z=\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis, hyperbolic-functions

Hi I need help finding the poles and the order of the poles of the following function:

$$\left(\cosh\frac1{z-\pi}\right)^2$$

and the residue at $z=\pi$.

I have tried a number of different methods including putting the function in exponential form but nothing seems to work, if someone could give some insight that would be great.

Comment: Which exponential form did you get? It's not too hard to find the result in the right form.

Comment: Is it $$\left(\cosh\left(\frac{1}{z-\pi}\right)\right)^2$$ or $$\cosh \left(\frac{1}{(z-\pi)^2}\right),$$ by the way?

Comment: See [related problems and techniques](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/determine-and-classify-all-singular-points/346995#346995).

Comment: Look at each term in the sum individually. What are the singularities of $\exp\left(\frac{2}{z-\pi}\right)$?

Comment: Show $z=\pi$ is an essential singularity.  Does your textbook discuss residues at essential singularities?

Comment: @user138730 Why are you editing Charles question to reflect what *you* have tried?

Comment: @user138730 Not being able to comment due to lack of reputation doesn't justify changing another persons question to reflect your own thoughts. Post an answer stating what you think could help to answer the question. That way you gain reputation and will soon be able to comment on questions.