# Singularities of complex functions.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How do I determine the singularities of a function? What is a singularity? In the functions below which are the singularities?

a)$$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^4+2z)}$$
b)$$f(z)={e^{1/z}}$$

Comment: Does your textbook (or notes) have a definition of a "singularity"?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a singularity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a start. For $(1)$ advance as

$$ f(z)=\frac{1}{(z^4+2z)}=\frac{1}{z(z^3+2)}. $$

$$z^3 = -2 = 2e^{-i\pi+i2k\pi} \implies z = 2^{1/3} e^{\frac{-i\pi+i2k\pi}{3}},\quad k=0,1,2.  $$

Now you can see the singularities of $f(z)$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/determine-and-classify-all-singular-points/346995#346995).

For $(2)$ check the notion of [essential singularity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity).

Comment: uh... Mhenni I think you forgot to reduce the $z^4$ to $z^3$.

Comment: @BennettGardiner: It is corrected. Thanks for the comment.