# Compute $\oint \Bigl[ z e^{3/z} + \frac{\cos z}{z^2 (z - \pi )^3} \Bigr] \, dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Compute
$$\oint \left[ z e^{3/z} + \frac{\cos z}{z^2 (z - \pi )^3} \right] \, dz$$
$$|z| = 5$$

My question is how to do residue at 
$$\oint ze^{3/z} \, dz $$

Comment: Have you tried expanding $e^{3/z}$ using a Laurent series?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 no did i need to do it can u explain why?

Comment: As $z\to0$, then $w=3/z\to\infty$, so think of how $e^w$ behaves as $w\to\infty$.  Depending on whether $w$ moves along the real axis in the positive direction, or in the negative direction, or along the imaginary axis, $e^w$ may approach $\infty$ or $0$ or may oscillate.  So you have an essential singularity rather than a pole. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

As @JimmyK4542 suggested, let's expand $e^{3/z}$ using a Laurent series:
$$
e^z = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}
$$
We can plug in $3/z$ and get:
$$
e^{3/z} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(\frac{3}{z})^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{3^n}{z^nn!} = 1 + \frac{3}{z} + \frac{9}{2z^2} + \dots
$$
From here we get:
$$
ze^{3/z} = z + 3 + \frac{9}{2z} + \dots
$$

What is the residue of $ze^{3/z}$ then?

Answer (score 0):

You have two poles inside your contour. Namely $z=0$ which is an essential singularity and $z=\pi$ which is a pole of order $3$. For the first pole $z=0$ we will have the Laurent expansion around the point $z=0$

> $$ z e^{3/z} + \frac{\cos z}{z^2 (z - \pi )^3} = z\left(1+\frac{3}{z}+ \frac{9}{2!\,z^2}+\dots \right) + \left(\frac{1}{2\pi^3}-\frac{6}{\pi^5} - {\frac {3}{{\pi }^{4}z}}-{\frac {1}{{z}^{2}{\pi }^{3}}}+\dots \right). $$

I think you should be able to find the residue from the above Laurent series which corresponds to the pole $z=0$.

I let you finish the problem. See [related problems and techniques](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346990/determine-and-classify-all-singular-points).